# simple while loop does not register input() the second time

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm making a playAgain function that asks if a player wants to play the game again. I've been looking at the code and I don't know why my first iteration doesn't work.

The code does 3 things:

1. If the user answers anything starting with 'y', it will return true.
2. If the user answers anything starting with 'n', it will return false.
3. If the user answers with anything else, it will loop.

The code below will loop if not given a 'y' or 'n' answer, but answering with anything after the first loop will not break it. I can't figure out why.

```
def oldPlayAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    answer = input().lower()
    while True:
        if answer.startswith('y'):
            return True
        elif answer.startswith('n'):
            return False
        else:
            print ('That is not a valid answer.')
            print ()
            oldPlayAgain()
```

This one works. But it seems similar to the first one?

```
def playAgain():
    answer = ''
    while not (answer.startswith('y') or answer.startswith('n')):
        print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer.startswith('y'):
            return True
        elif answer.startswith('n'):
            return False
        else:
            print ('That is not a valid answer.')
            print ()
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the second version, you ask for input in every iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the first version is that when `oldPlayAgain` is called again, a new while true loop is ran. It's fairly simple to see why if you draw out the call stack

```
oldPlayAgain -> Answer invalid call oldPlayAgain
    oldPlayAgain -> Answer invalid call oldPlayAgain
        oldPlayAgain -> ?
        ....
```

and since there no way to change `answer` once you have entered it when the function is first called, it is not possible to exist the program normally once an invalid input is given

```
oldPlayAgain -> Answer invalid, call oldPlayAgain
    oldPlayAgain -> Answer invalid, call oldPlayAgain
        oldPlayAgain -> Answer y, return
    oldPlayAgain -> Answer invalid, call oldPlayAgain (since `answer` is the same as the one in two level up)
        oldPlayAgain -> ?
```

Comment: thanks! I think I get it. Basically, if I answer 'y' after it starts looping, it exits THAT nested function but not the one above it (which I started by typing an invalid answer). Does that sound right?

Also, how would I fix the first one to make it work like the second function?

Comment: Yes, you get the idea. If you want to use recursion, you could do `return oldPlayAgain()`, that way the return would propagate upward. Also, don't for get to mark this as the accepted answer XD

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's what I was missing. And yes, accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

You must simplify a little bit your function and put the input inside the infinite loop:

```
def oldPlayAgain():
    while True:
        answer = input('Do you want to play again (yes or no)?: ').lower()
        if answer.startswith('y'):
            return True
        elif answer.startswith('n'):
            return False
        print ('That is not a valid answer!')
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo. If you look at condition 3 though, I do want the program to keep asking until it gets an accepted response.

Comment: and that is what the code does, no? Have you tested the code?

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry, I did not test it. I like this! Much more simplified.

Comment: I'm missing my points, but that's ok. I'm glad you have enjoyed it anyway. As Tim Peters says: "Simple is better than complex".

Comment: unfortunately I still can't upvote because I don't have 15 rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your first function (`oldPlayAgain`). If we simplify it, and convert your code to pseudo-code, this is basically what it looks like:

```
def oldPlayAgain():
    prompt user and get their input
    loop forever
        if input is "yes" or "no", return
        otherwise call the oldPlayAgain function
```

Now, let's say that the user types in something that isn't "yes" or "no". If so, what will happen? You'll call the `oldPlayAgain` function, and Python will prompt the user again. If you don't type "yes" or "no" again, Python will call `oldPlayAgain` for the *third* time, etc.

Your second function doesn't do that. if the user types in something other then "yes" or "no", you don't call a function, you just move back up to the top of your loop and ask for input again.